# Direct editing of Microsoft Office files on the server (Plone)

Tags: ms-office, plone, webdav

Is the following behavior possible (using some features of Microsoft Office not very well known by a Linux guy)

- Upload Microsoft Excel (or some other office file in Plone) as File content type
- Save
- When you click the file next time it opens directly in Microsoft Excel
- When pressing Save in Excel it directly updates the file on the server, not the local temporary copy

I think Microsoft Office provides some APIs to do things like this but I have no idea how they work. Some Webdav URLs maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Enabling external editing and using [Zope External Editor Client](http://plone.org/products/zope-externaleditor-client) ([PYPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.zopeedit)) should to do just that (for Archetype -based content types), but it must be installed on all client machines and may have issues. The development version should also support Dexterity-based content types.